# Angular 2/4 : How to add form controls on dynamically created components?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I'm trying to use the ComponentFactoryResolver to create a reactive form.

All the components I want to add in that form are specifics, and implement the ControlValueAccessor interface.

So, my question is simple : How can I add form controls on component created dynamically with ComponentFactoryResolver, without modifying my components ?

At the moment, my code is as follows :

```
component: ComponentRef<any>;
form: FormGroup;

@ViewChild('container', {read: ViewContainerRef}) container: ViewContainerRef;

constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver, private fb: FormBuilder) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.form = this.fb.group({});
  const component: any = MyStringComponent;
  const factory: any = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory<any>(component);
  this.component = this.container.createComponent(factory);
}
```

And the template :

```
<form
  [formGroup]="form">
  <ng-container #container>

  </ng-container>

</form>
```

This code works fine, my component is injected where I want, and I can access its Inputs using this.component.instance.

So, where should I add my formControlName directive ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44181152/how-to-dynamically-add-ng-value-accessor-component-to-reactive-form

Comment: See [Dynamic binding for FormControlName in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42271787/573032).

Comment: RomanC that's not what I'm looking for
@yurzui I'm just trying your code, but I don't really understand how it works... However, I've tried to implement it, but I'm facing issues when I try to work with several FormGroup. Any idea ?

Comment: Here is another implementation https://toddmotto.com/angular-dynamic-components-forms

Comment: That's the tutorial I've followed but I don't know how to use it with components implementing ControlValueAccessor ?

Answer (score 3):

Having the same use-case, I found this solution posted in 2020 to perfectly solve your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63523127/2879716

The author provides [a link to StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamically-rendering-angular-ng-value-accessor?file=src/app/app.component.ts) which shows how you can implement a `FormControlOutletComponent` component which serves as a single entry point for different form controls. As an example, it renders a `CustomInputComponent` inside, which can be implemented any way you want. The only requirement is that it should implement `ControlValueAccessor` interface.

It adds one more layer of components nesting, so dynamic component creation actually goes inside of `FormControlOutletComponent`, not in your main form component.
The key code which answers your question is here:

```js
  // in FormControlOutletComponent's decalration
  public ngOnInit(): void {
    // 1. Get NgControl reference (defined by `NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR` provider)
    const ngControl = this.injector.get(NgControl);

    // 2. Resolve dynamic component factory and create a component instance
    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(CustomInputComponent);
    const componentRef = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);

    // 3. Important! Delegate all value-accessor-related work to the instance of the dynamic component
    ngControl.valueAccessor = componentRef.instance;
  }
```

As a result, your `FormControlOutletComponent` becomes itself a "proxy" for other dynamic form components.

So, to answer your original question - "where should I add my formControlName directive?", - you should add it (or `ngModel` directive) to the `<app-form-control-outlet>` component in your form's HTML template:

```html
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <app-form-control-outlet [formControlName]="'controlName'"></app-form-control-outlet>
  <!-- of course, you can render multiple components this way using ngFor -->
</form>
```

Note that `FormControlOutletComponent` doesn't implement `ControlValueAccessor` interface, though it defines `NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR` provider:

```js
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => FormControlOutletComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
```

It works like a magic. The only inconvenience I'm having with this solution is that I can't simply use standard HTML `<input/>` as a dynamic component - I have to create my own wrapper around it, with `ControlValueAccessor` interface, which simply proxies all the commands to the `<input/>`. If somebody knows how to simplify this, it would be great.